# plex cant see my file path help?

Tags: 21.10, budgie, nas, plex

Long story short, I switch to Linux from mac OS originally. First, I tried Pop OS and it was great. After seeing Budgie, I wanted to switch to Ubuntu.

I had followed this [article](https://acceptdefaults.com/2020/03/16/mounting-a-synology-share-in-ubuntu/#synology-share-setup) while using Pop to mount my Synology drives and get Plex up and running and was successful. However, after switching to Budgie, I followed the same article and Plex cant see the path to my movies.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: @guiverc The OP says they tried PopOS! but they switched to Ubuntu Budgie (21.10). They also state that they *did not* have a problem on PopOS! but that *they do have a problem on 21.10*.

Comment: @mchid Done (and deleted the initial comment).

Comment: As I read it, it was the addition of a second desktop (ie. adding Budgie desktop to a Pop OS system), but given Budgie is a desktop and the only OS mentioned is off-topic, yes it's unclear.

Comment: @guiverc If it were a matter of adding a new desktop then  it wouldn't make sense to redo the shares and Plex. So, here, I'm assuming the charitable position of giving the user the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @guiverc Yeah, I had to read it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you installed Plex Server as a SNAP (if you used the Ubuntu Software app then you certainly did because it's the only version available there).

So, you need to search it again, open its page, click the Permission button and enable access to mass storage devices. Without this setting it can only access your user area.